# Date is invalid in IE and Firefox but is chrome it works fine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

```
var stdate=document.forms["myForm"]["from"].value;
var endate=document.forms["myForm"]["to"].value;

var fromDate = new Date(stdate);
var toDate = new Date(endate);

alert(fromDate);
```

Input:
from: 19-Mar-2014 03:13:50 PM

Output: (in IE & Firefox)
invalid Date

in Chrome broswer:
Wed Mar 19 2014 15:13:50 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

What date format should I use so that all browsers support? Or how should I handle it?

Comment: This has some useful info that may help: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: w3schools as always features some seriously lacking docs ... the `dateString` is listed, but isn't specified at all...

Comment: the Javascript `Date` object has some cross-browser quirks that can trip you up. If you're working with date strings as input, I recommend using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) as a wrapper to avoid some of these kinds of issues.

Comment: I would use an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted string in UTC as my input, but then manually [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) this string into parts and feed them into my [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor thus avoiding date parsing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, `new Date(`*`datestring`*`)` is all you need. But you need to chose the format carefully.

Here's a nice compatibility table: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

The short version is this:

- Dates only? use `YYYY/mm/DD`; **never** use hyphens in this format
- Need time, but local time is OK? use `YYYY/mm/DD HH:MM:SS`; again, no hyphens
- OK to ignore IE<9? Consider using ISO8601 with whole seconds (`YYYY-mm-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`, or with time-zone)
- Need a UTC time in IE8? You'll have to do something clever. Xotic's answer looks good here.

Comment: This is how I solved my problem. I was using "-" which is not supported by iPhone safari.

Answer (score 0):

As documented on MSDN (IE) - the Date constructor supports either a timestamp or a Datestring in a Format supported by Date.parse. According to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) this is either RFC2822 or ISO 8601. some examples: `2011-10-10` or `Mon, 25 Dec 1995 13:30:00 GMT` should be valid arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> I would use an [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
>   formatted string in UTC as my input, but then manually
>   [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
>   this string into parts and feed them into my
>   [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)
>   constructor thus avoiding date parsing issues.

Example

```
var iso8601 = '2014-03-19T03:13:50.000Z',
    parts = iso8601.slice(0, -1).split(/[\-T:]/),
    dateObject;

parts[1] -= 1;
dateObject = new Date(Date.UTC.apply(undefined, parts));

console.log(dateObject.toUTCString());
```

Output

```
Wed, 19 Mar 2014 03:13:50 GMT
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/x7TjL/)